# How to properly reinforce a porch that inspector flagged for a "single member band joist"?

Tags: deck, beam, post

A friend of mine bought a house recently, and one item flagged by the inspector is the front porch. I offered to help them fix the problem. Whether that means doing it myself, or hiring a professional as suggested, I still want to understand the proper solution.

Here's the photos and description from the report, and my understanding of the solutions:

**Left side:**

> [image: Post attachment, left side, view under porch]

**Right side:**

> [image: Post attachment, right side]

> **Inadequate support noted under the front porch.** Single-ply beam supporting front porch. When a deck is constructed without the use of girders supporting the joists in their span, the "outer" band joist, that the joists run into, should be doubled up and considered a beam. A single member "band joist" was present here. Evaluation and repairs are recommended to be performed as needed by a qualified deck contractor.
>
> **Girder(s) nailed to support posts is improper construction.** Girder is improperly relying on the shear strength of nails. The most under-appreciated connection on a deck frame is probably the one between a post and the beam it supports. This joint is a critical load-path connection that needs to keep the post and beam aligned while properly transferring deck loads to the footing. A less obvious but equally important function is resisting uplift loads. And when a lateral force is applied to the post, the connection also has to resist beam rotation and post displacement. Girders should bear directly on posts with appropriate connecting and anti-torquing hardware. This is a potential safety concern and corrective repairs are recommended.

**Ideal solution:** Ideally, because it's too late to make a proper two-ply beam resting on top of the post, I'd add another 2x6 to the opposite side of the post and use z-shaped brackets to attach both sides to the post. Problem is that at the right side, there's steps leading down, so there's no longer any access to the opposite side of the post.

[image: z-shaped bracket won't work]

**Proposed alternate solution:** Instead I'll sister a second 2x6 to the existing beam, and screw the two together along their length. Then, to properly connect that to the post, I'll sister a 4x4 to the existing post (attached with carriage bolts) and use something like this to attach the post to the beam:

[image: post cap bracket]

Finally, I'll use hurricane ties to connect the joists to the reinforced beam.

[image: hurricane ties]

### Any issues with this solution? Are there other options that would be better?

Comment: Unless your friend is flipping the house, and thus needs to "pass" some home inspector fussing about it then, "do nothing until there's an actual problem" is probably plenty. It's clearly held together for a while already, and whether or not it's built to "today's best practices" the proof of a building being adequate is that it holds together in real life.

Comment: Agree that home inspectors are famous for finding things to write about. That said, a well attached 2x6 supporting the girder in the second picture wouldn’t hurt. And plates to tie elements together also wouldn’t hurt. I really don’t think you need to go crazy engineering the heck out of this.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I get that perspective, but the beam is held in place with just four nails right now. I can certainly see it lasting for years, or a heavy snow load and some kids jumping up and down might just bust it loose. As long as I'm under there shoring up the nails I figure I can add $20 worth of lumber and hardware to bring it up to snuff.